# How do you go through a list of strings using the series.str.contains function?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have credit card charge data that has a column containing the description for the charge. I also created a dictionary that contains categories for different charges. For example, I have a category called grocery expenses (value) and regular expressions (Ralphs, Target). I combined my values in a string with the separator `|`.

I am using the `Series.str.contains(pat,case=True,flags=0,na=nan,regex=True)` function to see if the string in each index contains my regular expressions.

```py
# libraries needed
# import pandas as pd
# import re

joined_string=['|'.join(value) for value in values]
the_list=joined_string
```

Example output: the_list=[Gas|Internet|Water|Electricity,VONS|RALPHS|Ralphs|PAVILIONS|FOOD4LESS|TRADER JOE'S|GROCERY OUTLET|FOOD 4 LESS|SPROUTS|MARKET@WORK"]

````
df['Description']='FOOD4LESS 0508 0000FULLERTON           CA'

The Dataframe contains a column of different charges on your credit card
```python
for character_sequence in the_list:       
    boolean_output=df['Description'].str.contains(character_sequence,regex=True)
````

For some reason, the code is not going through each character sequence in my list. It only goes through one character sequence, but I need it to go through multiple character sequences.

Comment: Is it possible that you got the indentation wrong? is the second line indented under the for, or is it the way it is in the question? If so, that's your problem!

Comment: Could you please share some example data and correspondingly some expected results?

Comment: No, I was just having a hard time with Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NickBosio Your list is not really a list of strings. What is the separator here? Is it `"|"`? Or, are you trying to use the contents of `the_list` variable as your regular expression string?

Comment: Please give a few more lines of example data for `df['Description']`.

Comment: @NickBosio I have made some changes to the question. Added correction for the definition of `the_list`, it was being defined both as a `list` and and as a `string`. It needs to be consistent. Preferably consider not using `the_list` to store a string of all the strings in `the_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no data to compare with, I will just present some dummy data.

```py
import pandas as pd

names = ['Adam','Barry','Chuck','Dennis','Elon','Fridman','George','Harry']

df = pd.DataFrame(names, columns=['Names'])
# Apply regex and save to column: Regex
df['Regex'] = df.Names.str.contains('[ae]', regex=True)
df
```

**Output**:

```
    Names   Regex
0   Adam    True
1   Barry   True
2   Chuck   False
3   Dennis  True
4   Elon    False
5   Fridman True
6   George  True
7   Harry   True
```

## Solution with another Example akin to the Problem

First, your `the_list` variable is not correct. Assuming it is a typo, I would present my solution here. Please note that `regex` or regular expression, when applied to a column of data, essentially means that you are trying to find some patterns. How would you in first place know/check if your pattern recognition is working fine? Well, you would need a few data-points to at least validate the regex results. Since, you only provided one line of data, therefore, I will make some dummy data here and test if the `regex` produces expected results.

**Note**: Please check the Data Prepeartions section to see the data so you can replicate and test the solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

# Make regex string from the list of target keywords
regex_expression = '|'.join(the_list)
# Make dataframe from the list of descriptions 
#   --> see under Data section of the solution.
df = pd.DataFrame(descriptions, columns=['Description'])
# Regex search results for a subset of 
# target keywords: "Gas|Internet|Water|Electricity,VONS"
df['Regex_A'] = df.Description.str.contains("Gas|Internet|Water|Electricity,VONS", regex=True)
# Regex search result of all target keywords
df['Regex_B'] = df.Description.str.contains(regex_expression, regex=True)
df
```

**Output**:

```
    Description                             Regex_A Regex_B
0   FOOD4LESS 0508 0000FULLERTON CA         False   True
1   Electricity,VONS 0777 0123FULLERTON NY  True    True
2   PAVILIONS 1248 9800Ralphs MA            False   True
3   SPROUTS 9823 0770MARKET@WORK WI         False   True
4   Internet 0333 1008Water NJ              True    True
5   Enternet 0444 1008Wager NJ              False   False
```

### Data Preparation

In a practical scenario, I would assume that in case of the type of problem you presented in the question, you would have **a list of words**, that you would like to look for in the dataframe column.

So, I took the liberty to first convert your string into a list of strings.

```py
the_list="[Gas|Internet|Water|Electricity,VONS|RALPHS|Ralphs|PAVILIONS|FOOD4LESS|TRADER JOE'S|GROCERY OUTLET|FOOD 4 LESS|SPROUTS|MARKET@WORK]"
the_list = the_list.replace("[","").replace("]","").split("|")
the_list
```

**Output**:

```
['Gas',
 'Internet',
 'Water',
 'Electricity,VONS',
 'RALPHS',
 'Ralphs',
 'PAVILIONS',
 'FOOD4LESS',
 "TRADER JOE'S",
 'GROCERY OUTLET',
 'FOOD 4 LESS',
 'SPROUTS',
 'MARKET@WORK']
```

Also, we make five rows of data where we have have the keywords we are looking for; and then add another row to it where we expect a `False` as a result of the `regex` pattern search.

```py
descriptions = [
                'FOOD4LESS 0508 0000FULLERTON           CA', 
                'Electricity,VONS 0777 0123FULLERTON           NY', 
                'PAVILIONS 1248 9800Ralphs           MA', 
                'SPROUTS 9823 0770MARKET@WORK           WI', 
                'Internet 0333 1008Water           NJ', 
                'Enternet 0444 1008Wager           NJ', 
]
```

Comment: @NickBosio Please take a look at the updated solution (there is section describing the solution for the specific problem you posed in the question) and let me know if that helped.